# How can i load an entity from another bundle in an entity?

Tags: symfony, entity, bundle

Let's say i have 2 entities. Card and User.
User it's in UserBundle and Card is in PublicBundle.

In user i have this function:

```
#namespace Kanban\UserBundle\Entity;
    /**
     * Add assignment
     *
     * @param \Kanban\PublicBundle\Entity\Card $assignment
     * @return User
     */
    public function addAssignment(\Kanban\PublicBundle\Entity\Card $assignment)
    {
        $this->assignment[] = $assignment;

        return $this;
    }
```

Every time i execute this command:

```
php app/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql
```

It throws this error:

```
    [Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\MappingException]                                                                    
  The target-entity Kanban\UserBundle\Entity\Card cannot be found in 'Kanban\UserBundle\Entity\User#assignm  
  ent'.
```

I've tried the statement:

```
use Kanban\PublicBundle\Entity;
use Kanban\PublicBundle\Entity\Card;
```

At the beginning of the file but shows the same error.
Any ideas on what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: can you show us your declaration of $assignment in your entity? (where you do your relation between user and card)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NM!,

Was a problem with the orm.yml file, changed:

```
manyToMany:
    assignment:
        targetEntity: Card
        cascade: {  }
        mappedBy: customer
        inversedBy: null
        joinTable: null
        orderBy: null
```

into

```
manyToMany:
    assignment:
        targetEntity: Kanban\PublicBundle\Entity\Card
        cascade: {  }
        mappedBy: customer
        inversedBy: null
        joinTable: null
        orderBy: null
```

And that solved the problem!